# How to filter empty drafts in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-search

I want to use Gmail's search to find all my empty replies or drafts (mostly because I quite frequency click in the reply text area and create a new draft without meaning to).

To test this out I created two draft emails, one with nothing at all (no subject, addressee, content, not even spaces), and one whose contents are `asdf` and searched for them like this:

- `in:draft smaller:513` — both drafts appear in search results
- `in:draft smaller:512` — neither appears in search results

How do I search in order to return ONLY the completely empty drafts?

Comment: Seems to me that the size is read in blocks. So anything 0-512 or 513-1024 is dropped in the same size block for your search.

Answer (score 2):

## Short answer

AFAIK it's not possible that Gmail search return only empty messages when you are searching them by size.

## Alternatives

Look for the messages that returns [in:draft smaller:513] to try to find a pattern that could be used to refine the search terms. I.E. a word in the signature, a greeting, etc.

## Protip

Temporarily disable the conversation view to avoid to get non-draft messages that are part of the same conversation that some of the drafts.

Answer (score -1):

This works for my test cases, but is not general:

`in:draft -{content:{}}`

It finds a draft with nothing in the message body.  Unfortunately it also finds things that *do* have messages.  I don't really understand it.

Comment: Does this work if you have any kind of automatic signature? I wasn't able to get it to work with any of my attempts.

Comment: No, this is really brittle and returns results that don't make sense at all.  I mean, searching for `{content{}}` returns lots of normal mails, not sure what the command is intented to do now that I've messed with it a bit.